# NSIS Scroll License Welcome Screen

Tags: nsis

I have an installer that is having problems interacting with the scroll license plugin. The installer works great without the plugin, this is what the plugin has me include:

```
!

include MUI.nsh

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW LicenseShow
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "EULA.txt"

unction LicenseShow
 ScrollLicense::Set /NOUNLOAD
FunctionEnd

Function .onGUIEnd
 ScrollLicense::Unload
FunctionEnd

Section A 
Section End
```

The problem I run into is here. If the Welcome page displays BEFORE the License page it will not be able to progress to the next screen because it is looking for a scroll bar and accept button. If I remove the WELCOME page everything works fine. Does anyone have experience with this plugin? or how I can get the plugin to ignore the MUI_PAGE_WELCOME?

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME <--- If I remove this Welcome page everything works great!
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "eula.rtf" 
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
```

Comment: I'm confused about what is in your file. Is it the first block or the second block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the line:

```
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW LicenseShow
```

Below the line (more specifically, directly above the MUI_PAGE_LICENSE line):

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
```

I used ExampleCheckBox.nsi as supplied from the ScrollLicense plugin and reproduced your behavior when I had:

```
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW LicenseShow
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE ExampleCheckBox.nsi
```

The problem went away when I moved the !define line to after the MUI_PAGE_WELCOME.

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW LicenseShow
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE ExampleCheckBox.nsi
```

I'm not familiar with this plugin but I suspect there is some kind of side-effect that disables the Next button of the next displayed page...

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are missing is how the example needs to fit into the "flow" of the other MUI pages.

```
!include MUI.nsh

;;this goes before the License page if you want it first.
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME

;;now add the example stuff
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW LicenseShow
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "EULA.txt" ;;update for what file you want to include!

Function LicenseShow
    ScrollLicense::Set /NOUNLOAD
FunctionEnd

Function .onGUIEnd
    ScrollLicense::Unload
FunctionEnd

;;now continue with the rest of the pages
;;and we *don't* repeat the MUI_PAGE_LICENSE
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
```