# Invalid command ScrollLicense::Set /NOUNLOAD

Tags: nsis

I wrote **NSIS** by referring [NSIS Scroll License Welcome Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389025/nsis-scroll-license-welcome-screen)

```
!include "MUI.nsh"

Name    "ScrollLicense Test"
OutFile "ScrollLicense.exe" 

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW LicenseShow
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE EULA.txt

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

LicenseForceSelection checkbox

Function LicenseShow
  ScrollLicense::Set /NOUNLOAD
FunctionEnd

Function .onGUIEnd
  ScrollLicense::Unload
FunctionEnd

Section "A Section"
;some things to install
;...
SectionEnd
```

my code is same one but while compiling it throws error 
Invalid command `ScrollLicense::Set /NOUNLOAD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a third-party plugin that is not provided by the NSIS setup, you need to put the plugin dll (in your case `ScrollLicense.dll`) into the `Plugins` sub-directory of your `Program Files\NSIS` directory (or whatever name you used when you installed NSIS).

It should fix the `Invalid command` error.